# why is gradle not printing the properties file?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to execute simple print statements from in gradle/groovy but I get error

```
extProgram = new Properties()
extProgram.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/version.txt"))

ext.appVersion=extProgram['version']

println ext.appVersion
```

This is the error I get

```
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "extProgram" on "root project 'appController'", value: "{}".
2.0.193
[buildinfo] Not using buildInfo properties file for this build.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/Documents/codebase/app-controller/build.gradle' line: 54

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'appConroller'.
> Could not find method $() for arguments [build_5vi6ltfrgdviipcvtfu5rthgs1$_run_closure3_closure22_closure23@411109d] on root project 'appController'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.972 secs
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because extProgram is assumed to be a property of the project.
Try this instead:

```
def extProgram = new Properties()
...
```

This defines extProgram as a local variable.

Comment: I want it to be property of the project so I can use it across different tasks.

Comment: In that case use: `ext.extProgram = ...`